# Amount of distinct numbers in a sequence of $k$ random numbers in range $[1,\ldots,n]$

Tags: probability, balls-in-bins

Let $D$ be the amount of **distinct** numbers in a sequence of $k$ random numbers in range $[1,\ldots,n]$ (n>k).
I want to show that:
$D=\Omega(k)$ with exponential high probability. I'm interested in the case where $k/n \rightarrow 0$, e.g., $k=\sqrt{n}$.

I tried the following approach:

$D$ is the amount of **nonempty** bins when throwing $k$ balls into $n$ bins.
$Y$ is the amount of **empty** bins when throwing $k$ balls into $n$ bins.
So, $D=n-Y$.

Now, using Chernoff bound and the fact that $\text{E}[Y]=ne^{\frac{-k}{n}}$:

$$\begin{align}\Pr(Y>(1+\delta)\text{E}[Y])\le 2^{-\delta \text{E}[Y]}\\
\Pr(D<n-(1+\delta)\text{E}[Y])\le 2^{-\delta \text{E}[Y]}\end{align}$$

where $\delta>2e-1$.

I want to find $\Pr(D<\beta k)$, but to do so I have to take $\delta=\frac{n-\beta k-\text{E}[Y]}{\text{E}[Y]}$ which is negative since $\text{E}[Y]\rightarrow n$.

What I'm doing wrong, or there is some other way to show that $D=\Omega(k)$ with exponential high probability? Or maybe this statement is wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Your first task is to make precise the asymptotics you consider: $k\to\infty$ and $n\gt k$ but how? $n=k+1$, or $n\gg k$, or $n/k\to\alpha$ positive and finite?

Comment: Thank for the comment. I'm interested in the case where $k/n \rightarrow 0$, e.g., $k=\sqrt{n}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> so I have to take $\delta=\frac{n-\beta k-\text{E}[Y]}{\text{E}[Y]}$ which is negative since $\text{E}[Y]\rightarrow\infty$ (first version of the question), or $\text{E}[Y]\rightarrow n$ (revised version of the question).

Not quite...

- First, the mean of $Y$ is not what you write but $\mathbb E(Y)=n\left(1-\frac1n\right)^k$.
- Second, $\delta$ has the sign of the numerator divided by $n$, which is
  $$
  \gamma=1-\beta\frac{k}n-\left(1-\frac1n\right)^k.
  $$
  For every fixed $\beta\lt1$, when $n\to\infty$ with $k\ll n$, one gets 
  $$
  \gamma=1-\beta\frac{k}n-\left(1-\frac{k}n+o\left(\frac{k}n\right)\right)\sim(1-\beta)\frac{k}n,
  $$
  hence $\gamma\gt0$ for every $n$ large enough.

**Edit:** One can control the distribution of $D$ as follows. Consider the event $[D\leqslant k-i]$ and choose the $k$ numbers sequentially. Then $D\leqslant k-i$ means that at least $i$ times, one chooses an already chosen number. This happens each time with probability $\leqslant\frac{k}n$ and there are $\binom{k}i\leqslant2^k$ ways of choosing these $i$ moments, hence $\mathbb P(D\leqslant k-i)\leqslant2^k\left(\frac{k}n\right)^i$ $(\ast)$.

For example, $\mathbb P(D\leqslant\frac12k)\leqslant\mathrm e^{-\Lambda(n,k)}$ with $\Lambda(n,k)=-\frac12k\log\left(\frac{k}n\right)-k\log2$. One sees that, if $1\ll k\ll n$, then $\Lambda(n,k)\gg k$ hence the control on $\mathbb P(D\leqslant\frac12k)$ is at least exponential in $k$.

**Edit 2:** To see that $(\ast)$ holds, for every subset $I$ of $\{1,2,\ldots,k\}$ of size $i$, call $A_I$ the event that at every time in $I$ one chooses an already chosen number and at every time not in $I$ but earlier than some element in $I$ one chooses a new number (at every time not in $I$ later than the whole set $I$, the choice is free). Then the events $A_I$ are disjoint and their union over every $I$ of size $i$ included in $\{1,2,\ldots,k\}$ is $[D\leqslant k-i]$. There are exactly ${k\choose i}\leqslant2^k$ such sets $I$, and for every such set $I$, $\mathbb P(A_I)\leqslant\left(\frac{k}n\right)^i$. The upper bound of $\mathbb P(D\leqslant k-i)$ follows.

Comment: Thanks Did! I will check it tonight.

Comment: No, it didn't work... to use this formula ($2^{-\delta \text{E}[Y]}$), we have to ensure that $\delta > 2e-1$ which is not the case here...
And if I use the general Chernoff bound:
$$\Pr(D<n-(1+\delta)\text{E}[Y])\le \left(\frac{e^{\delta}}{(1+\delta)^{1+\delta}}\right)^{\text{E}[Y]},$$
I get that this probability goes to 1 and not to 0...
So maybe the statement that $D=\Omega(k)$ w.h.p. is not correct?

Comment: Can you indicate a reference of this Chernoff bound *restricted to $\delta\gt2\mathrm e-1$*, that you are using? (Note that since you pretended that $\delta\lt0$ was the problem you were facing, I debunked *that*.)

Comment: Here is the source: http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~celio/peer2peer/math/chernoff-bounds-canny.pdf

Comment: Hmmm, rather unconventional, I would say. // Anyway, see Edit.

Comment: Very nice proof. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did, in your analysis in the Edit section,
I think that $$\Pr(D\le k-i)=\sum_{u=1}^{i}\Pr(D=k-u)\le \sum_{u=1}^{i}\binom{k}{u}\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^u.$$
I mean that there is a need for the summation. What do you think?

Comment: @Michael No need for a summation, this is why the $2^k$ prefactor is there.

Comment: But $2^k$ is the stands for the upper bound on $\binom{k}{i}$, no?

Comment: Forget my last comment and see Edit 2.

Comment: I got the point, Did. But I think that the total number of subsets $I$ is $2^k$ and not $\binom{k}{i}$. This $\binom{k}{i}$ is the number of subsets of size exactly $i$. So, to my opinion, writing $\binom{k}{i}$ is a bit misleading...

Comment: No. Please read: *for every subset $I$ of {1,2,…,k}* **of size $i$**, *call $A_I$ the event*... and, later on,  *There are exactly ${k\choose i}$*... **such sets** $I$.

Comment: You are right! Thanks again!